# How does happiness work?

Tags: kittens-game

In the tab Small Village in the Kittens Game, there is an option to send hunters (when there is enough catpower available) with a happiness percentage in front of it. How is this happiness calculated or influenced by me, and what effect does it have on anything (probably the resource gathering from the send hunters option?)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Happiness goes down by 2% for every kitten you have after the fifth kitten (so the sixth kitten will drop it by 2% from 100% to 98%)

Happiness is the efficiency of your kittens. For example, a farmer (without any upgrades) normally will yield exactly 1 catnip per tick, but at 98% happiness they'll only yield 98% of that (0.98 catnip per tick)

Hunters can bring in items from the forest (I've only seen fur and ivory), each will increase the happiness by exactly 10%, cumulative (getting both increases by 20%). The amount of each of them only affects how long the bonus lasts, not how many the happiness bonus is

EDIT:
Also, [Amphitheaters reduces unhappiness by 4.8%](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Buildings#Amphitheatre) each, which means that it will negate the happiness reduction effect by overpopulation, but can't actually increase happiness (so if you have only ever had 5 kittens, it will not increase the happiness)

EDIT 2: In reality, it looks like that as of v 0.9.6 Amphitheater does not actually reduce unhappiness by 4.8%. I have 18 kittens for a projected happiness level of 74%, unicorn raises it to 84%, yet 7 amphitheaters only brings it to 93%, about 1.8% each. I'll see if I can find more on this

Comment: Ahh, that's why my food production went up when I looted fur or ivory. I thought that it was used to produce catnip or something. But it was the happiness and therefor the effectiveness of the cats that influenced the catnip production.

Comment: Yes, happiness beyond 100% increases your efficiency. I also want to add that when I obtained a certain rare resource from hunting, my 90% happiness goes up to 100%. This happens only once (it doesn't matter how many of that resource I have), but whether this resource increases happiness by 10% or resets it back to 100% I can't say

Comment: It is as you answered. I did go from 88% to 108% with ivory and fur I found from a hunt (but just for less then a minute)

Comment: It definitely resets when the resources run out.  Also, I believe your first unicorn gives you a straight up +10% to happiness, and that's permanent, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Mathias711 Well, I didn't want to mention it because that'd have been a surprise to others who want to play, but I was referring to the Unicorn. Well I guess it's 10% increase instead of reset

Comment: Fun fact: your hunters can bring back a unicorn.  That's how I got mine.

Comment: There's also the amphitheater which reduces the effects of overpopulation by 5%. (Before: 18 kittens, 105% happy, 1 theater, after buying another one 106% happy). And then there is the trade post re: bonus duration.  (before: 0 trade posts, Fury -0.18 demand, ivory -0.13 demand.  After: 1 trade posts Furs -0.17 demand, ivory -0.12 demand).

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the formula changed since the previous answer. This is what i figured out so far:

Happiness start at 100% up to 5 kitten. Some modifies apply, like every special resource (fur, ivory, spice) give +10% (so if you have fur and ivory, you get 120%). Unhappiness is also simply added to this %, so 24% unhappiness (17 kitten) + ivory + fur = 96% happiness.

Spice, Karma and some other things also effect happiness by a flat %.

Amphitheaters affect unhappiness. Unhappiness start at 0% for 5 kitten, and goes up by 2 for every kitten beyond 5. (So 2% at 6 kitten, 20% at 15 etc.) Amphitheaters only affect this modifier in the happiness formula. If you have 10 kittens and 10 amphitheaters, you get 10% unhappiness * 0.52 amphitheaters bonus = 5.2% unhappiness. If you have only fur, that would result in 104% (rounded) happiness.

To be clear: The amphitheaters bonuses are added up, so the formula is  1 - (# of theaters * 0.048) and not 0.952^(# of theaters) as some might expect. This hold true for all buildings, both those that decrease and increase production. A mine gives 20% bonus flat, and a tradepost decreases rare resource consumption flat.  <s>Unhappiness might reach 0 at 21 amphitheaters and rare resource consumption might reach 0 at 25 tradeposts.I cant tell what happened beyond that because i haven't reached that yet - those buildings will be ridiculously expensive at that point.</s>

After 10 tradepost you get diminishing returns, i suspect this i the same for amphitheaters and other buildings that decrease some need. See [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184936/is-it-possible-to-stop-the-consumption-of-rare-resources).

Fur, ivory and spice are consumed on use. Once they run out, the happiness bonus you got from them goes away. Unicorns and karma do not get consumed, so once you have these there happiness bonus is permanent.

Comment: I already have enough hunters and tradepost's to make my furs and ivory last forever. In fact, i think tradeposts work the same as amphitheaters, there bonuses are added instead of multiplied, so at 25 tradepost's, your rare resource consumption will be 0. - i considered that a bit out of scope, but i guess i can add the way amphitheaters bonuses add.

Comment: 25 tradeshops do NOT give a 0 consumption. I've got 25right now and I do not have enough ivory at the moment. Fur is going well, even some spares for amphitheaters.

Comment: Interesting. Can you share how many cats and ivory consumption you have? (Btw, i do need to send my cats out to hunt all the time to make enough fur and ivory).

Comment: I don't think it is relevant anymore, but: 25 tradeposts, 28 kittens, -0.060 fur consumption, -0.042 ivory and -0.006 spice.

Comment: That's 10 times less then i have on 11 tradeposts. Perhaps 26 pushes you over. I'm running 5 hunters with Composite Bow, Bolas and Hunting Armor to keep up thou.

Comment: Oh, we got a answer [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184936/is-it-possible-to-stop-the-consumption-of-rare-resources). Diminishing returns after 10 tradeposts.