# Is it possible to stop the consumption of rare resources?

Tags: kittens-game

The Tradepost note mentions that it reduces rare resource consumption by 4%.  By my calculations, 25 Tradeposts would mean a 100% decrease to rare resource consumption.

Does this mean after building enough Tradeposts, resources like furs, spices, and ivory will stop being depleted by default?

Comment: That really depends on whether it's 4% of base or 4% of current. I suspect it's the second, otherwise it seems like it would be too easy to get a free happiness boost.

Comment: It seems to be 4% base, but another user reported 25 tradepost did not decrease his rare resource consumption to 0, so i guess the answer is no. [link](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184385/how-does-happiness-work/184915?noredirect=1#comment250682_184915)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, it is not. Part of the game code includes the following:

```
getHyperbolicEffect: function(effect, limit){
    var absEffect = Math.abs(effect);
    var maxUndiminished = 0.75 * limit; //first 75% is free from diminishing returns
    if (absEffect <= maxUndiminished) {
        //Not high enough for diminishing returns to apply
        return effect < 0 ? -absEffect : absEffect;
    }
    var diminishedPortion = absEffect - maxUndiminished;
    var delta = .25*limit; //Lower values will approach 1 more quickly.
    // The last 25% will approach .25 but cannot actually reach it
    var diminishedEffect = (1-(delta/(diminishedPortion+delta)))*.25*limit;
    var totalEffect = maxUndiminished+diminishedEffect;
    return effect < 0 ? -totalEffect : totalEffect;
}
```

This function is used in basically every case where the value of something is a reduction. Thus, the bonus from Pastures, Tradeposts, etc. is run through it. A few seconds in Excel gives the following chart:

[image: Chart of the diminishing returns function]

In essence, up until 75% reduction, everything works exactly as you would expect; ten tradeposts give a net reduction of 40%. Past that, there is a sharp curve of diminishing returns; every new Tradepost is still improving the consumption rate, but by less than the one before.

There is hope, however, for two of the resources involved. Once you unlock the Mint building (requires Architecture), it will provide Furs and Ivory in exchange for some Catpower; by that point, you'll likely have enough tradeposts that just a single mint running will give you a net gain to both resources, allowing them to stay above 0 while idle for long stretches.

As a note: This function is generally **not** used anywhere the bonus from something is an increase. So, e.g., the Workshop boost to crafting effectiveness can stack forever - get a hundred of them somehow, and you're getting +600% crafting power.

Comment: You da real MVP.

Comment: How did you convert that function to Excel? I have zero experience with Javascript and can't figure out the translation.

Answer (score 4):

I have 29 tradeposts and while my consumption is now *very* low, it is not zero.  With my Mint turned off and 57 kittens, I consume 0.27 furs, 0.19 ivory, and 0.03 spice per second (note, that's NOT per tick).  With a single Mint, my fur and ivory production are positive (Mints don't affect Spice).  On average, when I find spices once while trading, they last for 45 minutes to an hour, so I can get enough easily to keep my happiness maxed out overnight.

Proof, possible spoilers for mid-game stuff:

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Stoicism reduces rare resource consumption by 50%. Combined with at least 13 trade posts to get over a total of 100% rare resource usage reduction, it may be possible. But there may be game code preventing this from working or like the top post above shows, there are diminishing returns to the rare resource reduction but I'm not sure if that applies to just the trade posts or the combined total of rare resource reduction.