# What do starEventChance and starAutoSuccessChance mean for the Observatory?

Tags: kittens-game

I'm confused as to what starEventChance and starAutoSuccessChance mean for the Observatory.  If they're just percentages, why wouldn't there be a percentage sign?  And a 20% increase in chance grows quickly, even if there's diminishing returns ([ref.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/184940/126434)).  So this doesn't seem to be the right interpretation.

This is the hover image:

[image: Observatory]

*Question*: What do starEventChance and starAutoSuccessChance mean for the Observatory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

starAutoSuccessChance increases the chance that an astronomical event succeeds automatically.  The value there does end up operating as a percentage.  The automatic success increases by 1% for every Observatory.  So if you had 20 Observatories, you would get an automatic success on average 1 in 5 events, 20%.  I believe this is subject to diminishing returns, but there is a workshop upgrade that provides 100% automatic success long before you should have 100 Observatories to test it. (There is actually another answer which details the formula behind it [here.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/185104/95753))

starEventChance increases another variable in the same way for providing the astronimcal events in the first place.  Trying to find a formula to translate what the value would do, but the base chance is supposed to 0.25% per day.  I believe the 20 would simply add on to that (making 0.45% per day, and climbing upward from there).

Answer (score 4):

In additions to Radhil's answer, the *starEventChance* indicates the chance to get a star on a given day. The base chance is indeed 0.25%. Every 20 points increase the chance by 0.20%. This is because *chance*, the variable in the source code, is compared with a random integer between 0 and 10000. The relevant code is below (I omitted quite some stuff, but it's not necessary for your question).

```
var chance = 25;    //25 OPTK of event per day  (0.25%)
chance += this.game.bld.getEffect("starEventChance");

if (this.game.rand(10000) < chance && this.game.bld.get("library").val > 0){
    var autoChance = this.game.bld.getEffect("starAutoSuccessChance");  //in %
    var rand = this.game.rand(100);

    if(rand <= autoChance){
        dojo.hitch(this, this.observeHandler)({}, true);
    }
}
```

So *starEventChance* is in hundredths of percentages, giving 0.20% bonus for each 20 points, and *starAutoSuccessChance* is in percentages, yielding 1 extra procent chance of automatically succeeding a celestial event for each Observatory you buy.