# When does building extra buildings start to give diminishing returns?

Tags: kittens-game

So in the kittens game I am at the year 239. My building count is ridiculously high now (93 catnip fields, 62 aqueducts, 56 pastures, 47 mines and etc).

I was wondering if it is possible to have a list to determine after which point there is no need to construct a specific building because the rate of return decreases.

What I mean by rate of return decreases is that I am pretty sure that if you build 25 tradeposts (which I have now), your rare resource consumption does not end up being zero

Comment: Your post ends in the middle of a word.  You might want to fix that.

Comment: Did a kitten make off with the end of your post?

Answer (score 18):

There is a difference in buildings that produce resources (or positively influence resource income) and buildings that reduces the consumption.

In the first case, build whatever you want. They will always add up to your total income. These buildings are for example catnip fields, aquaducts and temples (culture). Every catnip field you build extra will produce another 0.125 catnip per tick, excluding all bonuses. The same goes for the mine. Each mine will increase the mineral output by 20%. Note that this 20% is summed over, not multiplied. So 10 mines increase output by 200%, not 1.2^10 = 619%.

The second part is a bit more tricky. You already noticed that 25 tradeposts should result in a stop of consumption of the luxury goods (because 25 * -4% = -100%). That is indeed not the case. There is a diminishing function, explained [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184936/is-it-possible-to-stop-the-consumption-of-rare-resources/184940#184940), which will make sure that the reduction never reaches 100%. However, the diminishing does only start after 75%. So building 18 tradeposts (=72% reduction) gives the expected reduction, but 19 tradeposts will give around 75.8% something. Each tradepost you will build after this 19th one will increase the reduction by a smaller amount, as seen in the previously mentioned answer. Pastures (both normal and unicorns) are good examples (and tradeposts of course) of buildings who have this diminishing effect. An example of a diminished effect is the auto-observe chance for observatories.

This diminishing function is the same for every building and effect. So every building and effect increases linearly untill 75%, and after that it's slope will decrease (as shown in the figure in the [linked answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184936/is-it-possible-to-stop-the-consumption-of-rare-resources/184940#184940)).

Comment: Is it possible to have a full list of when the diminishing point is for each building? So for tradepost it is 75%, what about others?

Comment: The formula in the linked answer holds for all diminishings. I will add that in the answer

Comment: As the linked answer shows, they all use the same code (called get hyperbolic effect, even though the function isn't -exactly- hyperbolic, otherwise returns would be way too fast early on...)

Comment: Note that unicorn fields and pastures are cumulative in calculating their diminishing return, and it starts much earlier at -37.5%. So it isn't the same for all buildings.